# Change image of a button when clicking it Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to change the the image of a button when i click it and I'm using the method below:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var firstCard1: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func firstCard(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let blueCard = UIImage(named: "blue_back")
    firstCard1.setImage(blueCard, for: .normal)
}
```

I get an error on line 4 on the

```
for: .normal
```

It says

> Editor placeholder in source file.

Comment: I don't see any placeholder in your code. Normally cmd-b (build) will make that go away.  Did you try exiting Xcode and bringing it back up? Sometimes the editor gets out of synch with the contents.

Comment: I clicked on build and the error disappeared. Thanks. I didn't know that the editor sometimes gets out of synch, Ill have to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean and then build the project, which can be done with the following keyboard shortcuts:

<kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Either delete the line of code and re write it or clean and build your project